# Install Visual Basic in VS2015

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I want to install only the visual basic. How can I customize my installation excluding the additional features of VS2015? I have tried the custom installation but I am lost on what is the pre requisite applications needed to make VB projects.

Comment: How do you want to customize the installation?

Comment: Except for the little extra HDD space it requires, what's so bad about installing C# too? It can be good if you ever are to open a C# project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that by default, C#/VB, Web and some Desktop features are included.

[image: Default installation type]

Visual Studio allow you to custom this installation. However `A Custom installation automatically includes the components that are in a Default installation.`

This is from the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2h7fzkw.aspx) website.

You can't only install visual basic, sorry.

**EDIT :**

Even if you must install C#, you can specify your default environment setting to Visual Basic.

[image: Specify default environment]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just can't because is in the "pack" with c#